# Checkstyle checkstyle-checker.xml gets overriden when multiple configs are used

Tags: maven, static-analysis, checkstyle, software-quality

I need to separate the checkstyle plugin configs for production and test source code.
I managed to do it (see the config bellow), but there is '**checkstyle-checker.xml**' file which is always overriden and stays in the root of the target directory.

1. Is there a way to move it to /target/checkstyle directory?
2. Is there a way to separate it between prod and test source code?

[image]

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${maven-checkstyle-plugin.version}</version>
<configuration>
    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
    <failOnViolation>${maven-checkstyle-plugin.failOnViolation}</failOnViolation>
    <logViolationsToConsole>${maven-checkstyle-plugin.logViolationsToConsole}</logViolationsToConsole>
    <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
    <linkXRef>true</linkXRef>
    <skip>${maven-checkstyle-plugin.skip}</skip>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>checkstyle-validate</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <sourceDirectories>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourceDirectories>
            <includeTestSourceDirectory>false</includeTestSourceDirectory>
            <configLocation>/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
            <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/checkstyle/checkstyle-result.xml</outputFile>
            <cacheFile>${project.build.directory}/checkstyle/checkstyle-cache</cacheFile>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>checkstyle-validate-test</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <sourceDirectories/>
            <testSourceDirectories>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</testSourceDirectories>
            <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
            <configLocation>/checkstyle/checkstyle-test.xml</configLocation>
            <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/checkstyle/checkstyle-result-test.xml</outputFile>
            <cacheFile>${project.build.directory}/checkstyle/checkstyle-cache-test</cacheFile>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-checkstyle-plugin.checkstyle.rules.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

This file appears to be generated by maven-checkstyle-plugin as seen at https://github.com/apache/maven-checkstyle-plugin/blob/6d229a74b4a7eb2efc5fce287d932f6b5c250647/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/checkstyle/exec/DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.java#L733

Looking at https://github.com/apache/maven-checkstyle-plugin/blob/6d229a74b4a7eb2efc5fce287d932f6b5c250647/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/checkstyle/exec/DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.java#L765 it appears there is no way to override it's location and it will always go into the project's build directory.

I am not sure what purpose this file plays in the work the plugin does as this is not part of the base checkstyle library.